# Setting invidual bits in byte by group of bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

For example:

```
We have a byte A: XXXX XXXX
We have a byte B: 0000 0110
```

And now for example we want 4 bits from byte B on specific position and we want to put inside byte A on specific position like so we have a result:

```
We have a byte A: 0110 XXXX
```

Im still searching through magic functions without success.

Found similar and reworking it but still have no endgame with it:

```
unsigned int i, j; // positions of bit sequences to swap
unsigned int n;    // number of consecutive bits in each sequence
unsigned int b;    // bits to swap reside in b
unsigned int r;    // bit-swapped result goes here

unsigned int x = ((b >> i) ^ (b >> j)) & ((1U << n) - 1); // XOR temporary
r = b ^ ((x << i) | (x << j));
As an example of swapping ranges of bits suppose we have have b = 00101111 (expressed in binary) and we want to swap the n = 3 consecutive bits starting at i = 1 (the second bit from the right) with the 3 consecutive bits starting at j = 5; the result would be r = 11100011 (binary).
This method of swapping is similar to the general purpose XOR swap trick, but intended for operating on individual bits.  The variable x stores the result of XORing the pairs of bit values we want to swap, and then the bits are set to the result of themselves XORed with x.  Of course, the result is undefined if the sequences overlap.
```

Comment: Is your example (set bottom 4 bits of byteB as top 4 bits of byteA) the only problem you want to solve?  If not, can you be more specific about your other requirements?

Comment: `A = (A & 0xF) | (B & 0xF) << 4);`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your requirenments exactly, so correct me if I'm wrong:

You want to take the last 4 bits of a byte (B) and add them to the first for bits of byte A? You use the term 'put inside' but it's unclear what you mean exactly by it (If not adding, do you mean replace?).

So assuming addition is what you want you could do something like this:

```
A = A | (B <<4)
```

This will shift by 4 bits to the left (thereby ending up with 01100000) and then 'adding ' it to A (using or).

Comment: u didnt consider that the bits may vary, u cant OR smth like 1111 for example. I think i found an solution : clear the bits in byte x & ~((~ 0 << (8 - n)) >>> p);   But i have to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

> byte A: YYYY XXXX
>
> byte B: 0000 0110

and you want 0110 XXXX

so AND A with 00001111 then copy the last 4 bits of B (first shift then OR)

```
a &= 0x0F; //now a is XXXX
a |= (b << 4); //shift B to 01100000 then OR to get your result
```

if you wanted 0110 YYYY just shift a by 4 to the right instead of AND

```
a >>= 4
```

Comment: but this is only for one precise example, if u take A XXXX XXXX and want to put 0000 0110 on index 4 of byte A then u have X011 0XXX.

Answer (score 0):

Found an solution :

```
x = ((b>>i)^(r>>j)) & ((1U << n) -1)
r = r^(x << j)
```

where r is the 2nd BYTE, i,j are indexes in order (from,to).